# How do I load a Laravel Model using id and type name?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, polymorphism

Let's say I have a model `Comment` polymorphic through `Commentable`.  Now, if I create a new `Comment` with:

```
$comment->commentable_type = "Post";
$comment->commentable_id = 1;
```

I can always get the `Post` using `$comment->commentable();`.

My question is if I had a model's `type` and `id` is there a way I can instantiate and load that model without going through some polymorphic relationship like `commentable`?

I know in Rails I could do something like:

```
post = "Post".constantize.where(id: 1).first
```

Is there a way to do that in PHP/Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but you could do this and it would work:

```
$modelType = "App\Post";

$model = new $modelType;

$model = $model->find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Post;

class Comment extends Controller
{

  public function findId()
  {
    $post = Post::find(1);

    return $post;
  }
}
```